# Nesting models of the same type

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to create a sort of hierarchical structure where a parent model has children of the same model class, but it doesn't seem to work. When I do it, the children properties ends up with the max items in it. Probably not explaining this well, but [checkout this JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sidogaleho/1/edit) to see what I mean.

Is this sort of thing possible with Ember Data? Any ideas how to get it to work?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not specifying an inverse to the relationship and Ember-Data is getting confused. (If you don't know what an inverse is, [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693518/ember-understanding-inverse-relationships/25700619#25700619).) Luckily, it's a pretty simple fix. You can either declare a parent relationship, or just declare the inverse as null. If you change your relationship declaration to look like this, your JSBin works fine.

```
children: DS.hasMany('item', { inverse: null })
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried setting a parent as the inverse, but was still having issues with that. Didn't know you could set the inverse to null and it work.